# How to add conditionals for IE browsers between certain versions?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags, wp-enqueue-style

I know that `wp_script_add_data` and `wp_style_add_data` are the correct functions for adding IE conditionals.

***For example, this:***

```
wp_script_add_data( 'foo', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
```

***Would get you this:***

```
<!--[if (lt IE 9)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

---

**However, what if I want to do this (IE browsers *between* certain versions)?**

```
<!--[if (gt IE 6)&(lt IE 9)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just pass the different string?

```
wp_script_add_data( 'foo', 'conditional', '(gt IE 6)&(lt IE 9)' );
```

Which by the way is probably the same as:

```
wp_script_add_data( 'foo', 'conditional', '(IE 7)|(IE 8)' );
```

IE conditionals are pretty unreliable so need to be tested.

Comment: Hah, serious brain fart. Such a simple answer! Thanks majick... I'm curious though what you mean when you say IE conditionals are unreliable?

Comment: well since IE10 they are not supported, so for example !IE actually means !IE5-9... things like that, so it should be tested in IE compatibility modes... anyway, this may be of use or interest though: https://gist.github.com/padolsey/527683